# Filter data with variable at time of parsing

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hello and thanks in advance for your time.
I have a visualization that will live in an iframe and get a variable from the parent page, which will define what line to draw. I was able to do that and it's working.
Now my problem is that I am filtering at the time I am drawing the line. it works, but doesn't help if I want my Y scale axis domain to reflect min and max value of my selected entity, so I need to either:

- filter earlier while parsing the data (preferable)
- have a filter function in my Y scale axis domain to repeat the variable pull I have in my line function

I don't really know how to achieve that unfortunately.
I have a plunk here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/mtRewHwcRjQiIS4ymzoW

In the code I filter here:

```
rank.append("path")
.attr("clip-path", "url(#clipA)")
.filter(function(d) { return d.name === guid })
.attr("class", "line")
.attr("d", function(d) {return line(d.values); })
.style("stroke", "#158fcf" );       
});
```

I pull my max and min value for the Y scale axis here:

```
  xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {return +d.date; }));

  yScale.domain([
  d3.min(ranks, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.rank; }); }),
  d3.max(ranks, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.rank; }); })
  ]);
```

And this is where I parse my data:

```
// Read in data
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data){
if (error) throw error;

color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "date"; }));

// Format the data field
data.forEach(function(d){
d.date = parseDate(d.date);
});

var ranks = color.domain().map(function(name){
return {
name: name,
values: data.map(function(d){
return {date: d.date, rank: +d[name]};
})
};
});
```

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `rank` uses `ranks` as data, you can use the same filter:

```
var ranksFiltered = ranks.filter(function(d) { return d.name === guid });
```

Then, you use it for the yScale extent:

```
 yScale.domain([
  d3.min(ranksFiltered, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.rank; }); }),
  d3.max(ranksFiltered, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.rank; }); })
  ]);
```

Here is the Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/dx2CFXbvXJOEJUrFhYwI?p=preview